# What's the difference between "Solutions Architect" and "Applications Architect"?

Tags: architecture, definition

As far as I can see **Solutions Architect** is just a different "marketing" term for **Applications Architect**. Is that correct or are the roles actually different somehow? If so, how?

And yes, I have searched for this both on StackOverflow and on Google.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

**Update 1/5/2018** - over the last 9 years, my thinking has evolved considerably on this topic. I tend to live a little closer to the bleeding edge in our industry than the majority (though certainly not pushing the boundaries nearly as much as a lot of really smart people out there). I've been an architect at varying levels from application, to solution, to enterprise, at multiple companies large and small. I've come to the conclusion that **the future in our technology industry is one mostly without architects**. If this sounds crazy to you, wait a few years and your company will probably catch up, or your competitors who figure it out will catch up with (and pass) you. The fundamental problem is that "architecture" is nothing more or less than the sum of all the decisions that have been made about your application/solution/portfolio. So the title "architect" really means "decider". That says a lot, also by what it *doesn't* say. It doesn't say "builder". Creating a career path / hierarchy that implicitly tells people "building" is lower than "deciding", and "deciders" are not directly responsible (by the difference in title) for "building". People who are still hanging on to their architect title will chafe at this and protest "but I am hands-on!" Great, if you're just a builder then give up your meaningless title and stop setting yourself apart from the other builders. Companies that emphasize "all builders are deciders, and all deciders are builders" will move faster than their competitors. We use the title "engineer" for everyone, and "engineer" means deciding and building.

**Original answer**:

For people who have never worked in a very large organization (or have, but it was a dysfunctional one), "architect" may have left a bad taste in their mouth. However, it is  not only a legitimate role, but a highly strategic one for smart companies.

- When an application becomes so vast and complex that dealing with the overall technical vision and planning, and translating business needs into technical strategy becomes a full-time job, that is an **application architect**. Application architects also often mentor and/or lead developers, and know the code of their responsible application(s) well.
- When an organization has so many applications and infrastructure inter-dependencies that it is a full-time job to ensure their alignment and strategy without being involved in the code of any of them, that is a **solution architect**. Solution architect can sometimes be similar to an application architect, but over a suite of especially large applications that comprise a logical solution for a business.
- When an organization becomes so large that it becomes a full-time job to coordinate the high-level planning for the solution architects, and frame the terms of the business technology strategy, that role is an **enterprise architect**. Enterprise architects typically work at an executive level, advising the CxO office and its support functions as well as the business as a whole.

*There are also infrastructure architects, information architects, and a few others, but in terms of total numbers these comprise a smaller percentage than the "big three".*

**Note**: numerous other answers have said there is "no standard" for these titles. That is not true. Go to any Fortune 1000 company's IT department and you will find these titles used consistently.

The two most common **misconceptions** about "architect" are:

- An architect is simply a more senior/higher-earning developer with a fancy title
- An architect is someone who is technically useless, hasn't coded in years but still throws around their weight in the business, making life difficult for developers

These misconceptions come from a lot of architects doing a pretty bad job, and organizations doing a terrible job at understanding what an architect is for. It is common to promote the top programmer into an architect role, but that is not right. They have some overlapping but *not* identical skillsets. The best programmer may often be, but is not always, an ideal architect. A good architect has a **good** understanding of many **technical** aspects of the IT industry; a **better** understanding of **business needs and strategies** than a developer needs to have; excellent **communication skills** and often some project management and business analysis skills. It is essential for architects to keep their hands dirty with code and to stay sharp technically. Good ones do.

Comment: Very good points all around.  I agree that there are those wide spread misconceptions. +1

Comment: Good answer; makes me realise how little I miss working for Large Company X :)

Comment: OK, very good answer - I've accepted it. Clearly, those who post job ads for architect roles have no such understanding, but at least now I do if I get asked about it. :)

Comment: >>An architect is someone who is technically useless,

There are a lot of architects who did write code..

Comment: This helped me understand the different alot. Thanks!

Comment: very nice description. Good job.

Comment: IMHO Applications Architect is more commonly used (at least today) as one of members of the EA team - what you describe as application architect is to me known as a Software Architect. Otherwise this answer is still pretty much on the mark.

Comment: Great answer, though I agree with piers7 above, that what you call "Application Architect" is what I call "Software Architect" -- with Application Architect being a member of the EA group (TOGAF style). Anyway, I have a question: Can you point to any literature (papers, blogs, books, certifications) that a specific for the Solution Architect role? I find that it is very hard to find much on that role. It is always either the SW architect or EA architect roles that are written about. Maybe besides the EIP book.

Comment: Another question: Is there a standard somewhere that the Fortune 1k companies you mention refer to since they are aligned on your 3 role descriptions above?

Comment: @MSurrow a standard like TOGAF, no. Note I also wrote this more than 8 years ago, so things have shifted over time. From my POV, the word "solution" has migrated into sales, i.e. "Sales Engineer ~= Solution Engineer or Solution Architect". Also, a lot of companies are starting to eschew the title "architect" altogether, although smart ones still understand and can enumerate the functions architecture performs. I was one of the principals at my current company to drive getting rid of the title "architect" (even though I was one at the time). It has accumulated a lot of baggage over time.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: @RexM What title(s) did you propose as alternatives to something with "architect"?

Comment: I like this answer, as it is short and unambiguous. In this setup, what would you say an Domain Architect does? And isn't 'Platform Architect' just a synonym for 'Solution Architect'?

Comment: @RogierWerschkull my answer is a decade old... a lot of things have changed. Most of all that the term "architect" has so much baggage it's mostly harmful.

Comment: The number of upvotes is partly indicative of the fact that the title 'architect' has very often been used haphazardly and unscrupulously, by recruiters and /or organizations to either lure seasoned developers into an environment where they will not really have the scope of responsibility they are aspiring to, or they will have both responsibilities of an 'individual contributor' and 'architect' simultaneously.

Comment: Any software developer will make some 'architectural' decisions. Ideally someone that holds the title of architect has the experience to provide a general blueprint and  guidance as to how to build an application or solution in a manner that will best adhere to all concerns whether technological , business, or even political. In an ideal world this individual should not also be responsible for code deliverables, at least not in the same rate as other developers, but  be able to step in when a need is identified.

Comment: It also seems to me that the advent of cloud native 'solution' architecture or modernization has supported this, as the modularization of the solution architecture is much more clearly defined. However as a result it appears  that Cloud Native Solution Architects are expected to function as what one might consider a DevOps engineer.

Answer (score 7):

Basically in the world of IT certifications, you can call yourself just about anything you want as long as you don't step on the toes of a "real" professional organization.  For example, you can be a "Microsoft Certified Solution Engineer" on your business card, but if you write the magic phrase "Professional Engineer" (or P. Eng) you're in legal trouble unless you've got that iron ring.  I know there's a similar title for "real" architects, which I can't remember, but as long as you don't mention that you can be a "Cisco Certified Network Architect" or similar.

Answer (score 6):

No, an architect has a different job than a programmer.  The architect is more concerned with nonfunctional ("ility") requirements.  Like reliability, maintainability, security, and so on.  (If you don't agree, consider this thought experiment: compare a CGI program written in C that does a complicated website, versus a Ruby on Rails implementation.  They both have the same *functional* behavior; choosing an RoR *architecture* has what advantages.)

Generally, a "solution architect" is about the whole system -- hardware, software, and all -- which an "application architect" is working within a fixed platform, but the terms aren't that rigorous or well standardized.

Answer (score 5):

There are no industry standard definitions for Architect job titles -- Application/System/Software/Solution Architect all refer in general to a senior developer with strong design and leadership skills.  The balance of design, strategy, development (often of core services or frameworks) and management differ based on the organization and project.

The only "Architect" job title that really has a different meaning for me is "Enterprise Architect", which I see as more of a IT strategy position.

Comment: Yeah this is quite a good summary I think. Roles (other than EA) are rarely so sharply defined that the difference matters, and even when they are, they won't be in another organisation.

Answer (score 5):

There are valid differences between types of architects:

Enterprise architects look at solutions for the enterprise aligining tightly with the enterprise strategy. Eg in a bank, they'll look at the complete IT landscape.

Solution architects focus on a particular solution, for example a new credit card acquiring system in a bank.

Domain architects focus on specific areas, for example an application architect or network architect.

Technical architects generally play the role of solution architects with less focus on the business aspect and more on the techology aspect.

Answer (score 2):

An 'architect' is the title given to someone who can design multiple layers of applications that work together well at a high level. Anything that gets into a generic type of 'architect' without a specific type of technology (i.e. "Solutions", "Applications", "Business", etc) is marketing speak.

Comment: Yes, lol "business architect". You're exactly right. I agree its fine to be an "Applications Architect" or an "Infrastructure Architect" because you have specific expertise within a specific domain, but "Solutions architect" is pretty generic and you can bolt "Solutions" in front of anything really i.e. "Solutions Developer" or "Solutions Analyst" etc. It's all marketing/BS.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually quite a difference, a solutions architect looks a a requirement holistically, say for example the requirement is to reduce the number of staff in a call center taking Pizza orders, a solutions architect looks at all of the component pieces that will have to come together to satisfy this, things like what voice recognition software to use, what hardware is required, what OS would be best suited to host it, integration of the IVR software with the provisioning system etc.

An application archirect in this scenario on the other hand deals with the specifics of how the software will interact, what language is best suited, how to best use any existing api's, creating an api if none exists etc.

Both have their place, both tasks must be done in order to staisfy the requirement and in large orgs you will have dedicated people doing it, in smaller dev shops often times a developer will have to pick up all of the architectural tasks as part of the overall development, because there is no-one else, imo its overly cynical to say that its just a marketing term, it is a real role (even if it's the dev picking it up ad-hoc) and particulary valuable at project kick-off.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the same to me! Though I don't totally disagree with Oli. I'd give a selected few people the Software Architect title if they want it but experience tells me the people who would actually deserve the title of Software Architect usually aint that in to titles.

Comment: Fair enough call I gave you +1 but you have to remember that also a 150% programmer without communication skills is worse than a 110% programmer who can communicate awesomely, explain concepts and lead other programmers. This more often leads to an "architect" title as opposed to the 150% gun coder who can't lead others for $%^&... I.e. the grumpy troll who is the "best coder on paper" but everyone hates working with.

Comment: I didn't have the 150% programmer in mind with what I wrote. The ones I know as good architects are real programmers with a knack for the whole design process. They are always the first to learn about cool stuff and can communicate perfectly to anyone in the organization. Unfortunately these are hard to come by and if you don't know any programming how are you supposed to lead software development?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when I was consulting at Computer Associates, the marketing cry was 'sell solutions, not products'. Therefore, when we got a project and I needed to put on my architect's hat, I would be a Solutions Architect, as I would be designing a *solution* that would use a number of components, primarily CA products, and possibly some 3rd party or hand coded elements.

Now I am more focused as a developer, I am an architect of applications themselves, therefore I am an Applications Architect.

That's how I see it, however as has already been discussed, there is little in the way of naming standards.

Answer (score -9):

The spelling?

Seriously though - they're both BS job title fluffing. "Programmer" not good enough for you? Become an  "Architect"!

Really... What is the world coming to?!

Edit: I clearly hurt some "architects'" feelings!

Edit 2: Though I agree with the sentiments that the phrasing can be interpreted to mean some people deal with the whole problem domain (eg hardware, software, deployment, maintaining), most people who want to satisfy a client (and make more money) will provide a full service, if required, regardless of their title.

In real life, it's just marketing fluff.

Comment: Really? So in a company with 100,000 employees, who makes the high-level decisions which affect scores or hundreds of individual software projects? A "programmer"?

Comment: You're a manager... I don't see why people need to throw "architect" around as if they're somehow better. I'm a Level 32 Web Wizard. How'd'ya like d'em apples (of sarcasm +5)?

Comment: Because it's a different role... managers manage people. Architects are technical owners, not bosses.

Comment: Just because you've never worked with a real architect (or at least someone who deserved the title) and you can't imagine a scenario where such a role is needed, does not mean the role does not exist. This is not hypothetical, real people do the very thing I've described every weekday.

Comment: So, just to be clear.. you are saying that Frank Gehry is a part-time carpenter?

Comment: @SquareCog makes a good point. A physical building architect does not employ the carpenters or electricians, so he is not a manager. He is also not concerned with the minutiae of an electrician's work in the project. He spends his time at a higher level.

Comment: Another of many in this post that either live in a box and have no understanding of the role in larger organizations, or are far too salty and jaded to offer any constructive feedback

Answer (score -9):

When your title doesn't fit on your business card because you wear too many hats, then someone wordsmiths a nifty title for you.

e.g. Programming/IT/Project Management/Strategy/Business Analyst

Other ways to receive an architect title:

- You spend more time on the phone and at the whiteboard than you do actually developing working software.
- You spend more time helping people set up Outlook/Entourage than you do actually developing working software.
- You're really not that good of a coder to begin with.

Comment: The first 2 dotpoints were valid and in my case, the third one is totally invalid. I.e. I was an awesome and passionate coder to begin with (Just ask me??). But I do know of completely did architects who couldn't code themselves out of a teacup who ended up scoring this title. Look titles are one thing, just start your own company and be Founder, CEO, Architect, Developer, CIO and run the whole ship.